# VSCode Omnisharp is not working and code action is not available

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Hello all: I am having issue getting omnisharp to work on vs code. it seems to load without any error messages but as soon as I click on an underlined code error appears as below:

```
{
  "Type": "request",
  "Seq": 117,
  "Command": "/v2/getcodeactions",
  "Arguments": {
    "FileName": "c:\\Users\\timch\\Desktop\\workFolder\\AngularBlog\\Startup.cs",
    "Line": 44,
    "Column": 30
  }
}
[fail]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        ************  Response (5469.1211ms) ************ 
{
  "Request_seq": 117,
  "Command": "/v2/getcodeactions",
  "Running": true,
  "Success": false,
  "Message": "\"System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.\\r\\nCould not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. File specified could not be found \\r\\nCould not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. File specified could not be found\\r\\n   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)\\r\\n   at OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.Refactoring.V2.CachingCodeFixProviderForProjects.<>c.<LoadFrom>b__6_0(AnalyzerFileReference analyzerFileReference) in D:\\\\a\\\\1\\\\s\\\\src\\\\OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp\\\\Services\\\\Refactoring\\\\V2\\\\CachingCodeFixProviderForProjects.cs:
```

There are a lot more below but they are pretty much repeatedly complaining about the same thing. I have searched for this issue and tried to reinstall all nuget packages and vscode itself but to no solution. May I please get some help on this?

Thank you very much.

- removed .vscode and .vs and tried dotnet restore
- removed all nuget packages and reinstalled them
- add "omnisharp.path" = "latest" and "omnisharp.useModernNet": true,
- reinstalled vscode

Comment: Same here. Started in recent version. Did you figure it out?

Comment: My problem was that I tried the dotnet upgrade tool to try and upgrade from an older version. It added a couple of packages to my csproj file. It might be different in your situation but do try and remove each one and try the dotnet restore to see which package is the one in question. In my case it was Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers
Getting rid of it solved my issue, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was one of the package that was added that caused the issue when I was using the dotnet upgrade tool. Removing the package reference in the csproj file and running dotnet restore resolved my issue.